# Printing a double pointer to a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, double-pointer

A linked list defined as:

```
typedef struct linkedList_struct {
    short unsigned int num;
    struct linkedList_struct *next ;
} linkedList;
```

I'm trying to print out the `num` value of `**head` when `**head` is passed to the function

```
int function(linkedList **head) 
{
   printf("%X\n, head->num);  // I get error here: error: member reference base type 'linkedList*' (aka 'struct linkedList_struct *') is not a structure or union
}
```

How do I dereference this double pointer to a linked list node so that I can print out `head->num` value?

Comment: `linkedList**` is a *pointer-to-a-pointer-of-linkedList*, so `(*head)->num` should work.

Comment: @Ruks Thank you - that did it